# Android app - Access the YouTube Data API in RELEASE mode

Tags: java, android, android-studio, google-api

I made an Android app that works fine in **Debug** mode. It uses the YouTube Data API to get some data from the YouTube account of the connected user.

Everything works fine, but when I make the **release** apk, copy-paste it on my Android device and install it, my app doesn't have the access to the YouTube Data API. I get the message `"Access Not Configured. The API (YouTube Data API) is not enabled for your project. Please use the Google Developers Console to update your configuration."`

Is there a step to do to allow the release version to access Google APIs that is different than in debug mode? What did I miss?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, just needed to generate the release SHA1 footprint with

`keytool -list -v -keystore ~/pathToYourKeyStore/your_release_key.jks -alias yourKeyAlias -storepass yourStorePassWord`

then added this SHA1 followed by a `;` and the name of the package in "Android Applications" to my public access API key (in the Google Developers Console).

And, because I also use OAuth I had to create a new Client Id for the app with this new SHA1 certificate.

And then, wait for few minutes before it works (in my case anyway).

Comment: Hi , can we generate two client id for both debug and release sha1 fingerprint for this issue?

Answer (score 0):

I think you should browser key for your app.I had that error google map auoto complete example.I fixed use to browser key.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I don't understand how a browser key could authorize my app to access APIs. When I click on Create a key > Browser key, it asks for an authorized URL, and I don't have any website.

Comment: it is not authorized url.Its wants to you sha 1 key.You find sha1 code and paste.Lik this   **82:73:F4:70:D9:0D:73:77:C9:17:A3:95:45:BF:73:0A:DF:81:31:2D;astrology.appwox.com.astrology**   You dont forget.Eclipse sha1 and studuo is diffirent places

Comment: one second did you create your create android api key for dont working version.

Comment: I did not create a new API key for my release version, I just added the footprint SHA1 certificate and the package name to the list of the authorised app. I have then 2 lines under "Android applications" for my API key. The first one is the one with the SHA1 of the debug.keystore followed by the name of my package, and the second one is the SHA1 of my android.jks followed by the same package name.

Comment: Ho, nevermind, it works now. I think I just had to wait a little. Thanks for your help ;)

Answer (score 0):

How do I restrict my API key to specific Android applications?
You can restrict an API key to specific Android applications by providing a debug certificate fingerprint or a release certificate fingerprint.

Debug certificate fingerprint
For Linux or macOS:

```
$
keytool -list -v -keystore ~/.android/debug.keystore -alias androiddebugkey -storepass android -keypass android
```

For Windows:

```
$
keytool -list -v -keystore "%USERPROFILE%\.android\debug.keystore" -alias androiddebugkey -storepass android -keypass android
```

Release certificate fingerprint

```
$
keytool -list -v -keystore your_keystore_name -alias your_alias_name
Replace your_keystore_name
```

with the fully qualified path and name of the keystore, including the .keystore extension. Replace your_alias_name with the alias that you assigned to the certificate when you created it.